# Scheduling of WebDriver's `execute_script` with other Javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, dom-events

I am using Selenium WebDriver with Firefox.  I want to write a front-end spec that:

1. Clicks on a DOM element that has some on-click Javascript code bound to it;
2. Executes its own JS (using [evaluate_script](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session#evaluate_script-instance_method)) to read the result of executing step 1.

I do these two steps sequentially, without any pause between them.

Am I guaranteed that step 2 will run only upon completion of step 1's Javascript code?

Since [Firefox's Javascript runtime is single-threaded](https://blog.mozilla.org/luke/2012/01/24/jsruntime-is-now-officially-single-threaded/), I think I need to convince myself only that Firefox will run the on-click handler before running my `evaluate_script`; I don't need to worry about concurrent execution.  But looking through Firefox's [Click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) and [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) in general, there are no promises about when the handler(s) bound to the events will be scheduled.